# php json to javascript json format is not coming right as required result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

i am trying to achieve below json
Sorry to say but i am not getting which is issue.

required JSON screen shot with console : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fzMx.jpg

```
var requiredJson = {
        chart: {
            container: "#OrganiseChart-simple"
        },      
        nodeStructure: {text:{name:"Root"},children:[{text:{name:"naresh"},children:[{text:{name:"rahul1"}},{text:{name:"rahul123"}},{text:{name:"kapil1"},children:[{text:{name:"priya12"},children:[{text:{name:"amit12"}}]}]}]},{text:{name:"roshan"}},{text:{name:"Seppl"}},{text:{name:"pankaj1910"}}]}
    };
```

My try:

my try is giving me this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1XXD.jpg

my php json when i am using echo to json_encode($tree) :

`[{"text":{"name":"Root"},"children":[{"text":{"name":"naresh"},"children":[{"text":{"name":"rahul1"}},{"text":{"name":"rahul123"}},{"text":{"name":"kapil1"},"children":[{"text":{"name":"priya12"},"children":[{"text":{"name":"amit12"}}]}]}]},{"text":{"name":"roshan"}},{"text":{"name":"Seppl"}},{"text":{"name":"pankaj1910"}}]}] ;`

```
//$tree is a php array

var mytry = '<?php echo json_encode($tree); ?>';
 var requiredJson  = {
        chart: {
            container: "#OrganiseChart-simple"
        },

        nodeStructure: mytry 
    };
```

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ueo0k9ys/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the php output. They are telling the javascript compiler it is a string not array

```
var mytry = <?php echo json_encode($tree); ?>;
var requiredJson  = {
    chart: {
        container: "#OrganiseChart-simple"
    },

    nodeStructure: mytry 
};
```

Comment: result not expected : your try giving me this https://imgur.com/a/D2vzV

Comment: with your try nodeStructure is coming as array but it should be an object

Comment: So adjust it server side to return what you expect

Comment: Not if the structure isn't as expected

Comment: ok. I converted my PHP code and now i got this in javascript   Object [ Object ]  . how can i access second Object  ?

Comment: See [access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)